# Travel from A to B in finite number of days?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Suppose, the distance between city A and city B is 1. Each day, I complete $90\%$ of the residual distance. For example, on day 1, I will travel 0.9, on day 2, I will travel $90\%$ of the left distance to city B which is $0.9+0.9(1-0.9)$. By the same logic, on the third day, the distance past will be $0.9+0.9(1-0.9)+0.9(1-0.9-0.9(1-0.9))$, and so on.

**Question**

1. Will the journey be completed in the finite number of days? How could I prove/disprove it?
2. What is the probability that, the total distance travelled up to day $k<\infty$ is less than 1? It means  find $\Pr(D_k<1)$?

Comment: What if you concentrate on the distance left untravelled instead of the distance traveled? How far are you from city B on the n-th day?

Comment: @JonathanZ (1- the total travelled distance). We have to get a recursive relationship for that. I guess the sequence will be in this form: $0.9 + 0.9-0.9^2-0.9^3...-0.9^n$. I have to double check.

Comment: It depends on your philosophical assumptions.

Comment: @blargoner But can we say that $\exists k < \infty : \Pr(D_k<1-\epsilon)=0$, where $\epsilon>0$ is a arbitrary positive value. Or should I put some additional constraints there?

Comment: @entropy - I recommend you stop using "90% traveled" in your calculations, and start over from the beginning and use "10% untravelled". Your arithmetic will be so much easier.

Comment: Also, the way your problem is stated it is completely deterministic. You gain nothing by adding probability to the answer. Did you have a specific reason to think it would help?

Answer (score -1):

This is one of [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes). It essentially highlights a discrepancy between physical reality and an idealised mathematical model of that physical reality. In the idealised geometrical model a sequence of points $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ that progresses towards $B$ making a fractional amount of progress each day will never reach $B$. In physical reality, a person or a vehicle can't make arbitrarily small steps (even if it's driven by a "continuous" engine like an electric motor, there will be latency in the engine and a non-zero time lag while the control system issues commands to the engine).

Comment: But can we say that $\exists k < \infty : \Pr(D_k<1-\epsilon)=0$, where $\epsilon>0$ is a arbitrary positive value. Or should I put some additional constraints there?

Comment: It feels like by the OP specifically setting the speed, which gets progressively smaller each day, this is no longer one of Zeno's paradoxes. Zeno is "how can one do an infinite number of things in finite time", but the OP is imagining an infinite length of time. Your observation that space is not infinitely divisible applies to their description, but I'd describe that as "in the spirit of Zeno".

Comment: @JonathanZ to be honest, I am trying to prove an optimization algorithm, more specifically, cross entropy algoruthm. I believe I could prove that it converges. But I want to show that the convergence happens in finite number of iterations. The algorithm is based in the adaptive importance sampling where at each iteration we truncate some fixed fraction of the support. Maybe you have some ideas how I can do that. Or maybe you have a proof of another algo which I can mimic?

Comment: @Rob Arthan I do not kniw whether you receive notifications when I comment on Johnatans comments.

Comment: @JonathanZ it's what is called the dichotomy paradox on the Wiki page I cited, but with the ratio changed from $1/2$ to $9/10$.

Comment: If you are looking at convergence properties of a specific algorithm, then you need to say more about the algorithm for us to help you. You can design algorithms with very unruly convergence properties - an algorithm might appear to give a result that gets closer and closer to $0$ after a huge number of samples but then wander off and converge to $1$.

Comment: @entropy - Well, if your algorithm behaves like you've described, than at step $n$ there will always be $(0.1)^n$ of your original interval "untraversed", so it will not converge in a finite number of steps. But if you set some small, non-zero tolerance, it will get below that in a finite number of steps

Comment: Yet more unexplained down-votes - you people live very sad and nasty lives.

Comment: Well, I can't speak for the other down vote, but I thought my comment was a pretty good explanation of why I thought this wasn't a helpful answer.

Comment: @JonathanZ: I wrote "one of Zeno's paradoxes". This is exactly analogous to the dichotomy paradox as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes) and that is not as you described it. Could you elaborate on why you disagree?

Comment: Yes, I initially went and read that page, and the dichotomy paradox was the one I figured you were referring to, as it uses much of the same set up as the question. I gave the reasons for why I didn't think the OP's question was an intense of it in my first comment.